# Appearance of Java Security dialog

Tags: java, security, jar-signing, jarsigner

The Java Security dialog is shown when loading a signed applet.

What does the Java Security dialog look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Java Security Dialog]

The security dialog might appear differently (and have different text) depending on the circumstances, but it looks roughly as above.

If the 'digital signature cannot be verified' as in that message in the dialog, then:

- `Always trust` will default to false.
- It will be ignored even if selected.
- No `Name` or `Publisher` will appear.  That image shows the prompt as it appears in older JREs.

Here is how the [NASA World Wind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/1.2.0/demos/) prompt appears in a Java 7 JRE for a verified certificate that has **expired**.  The plug-in will also not tick the `Always allow` check-box by default.

[image]

Comment: The NASA World Wind link has changed. It's now: http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/ where you can follow the links for the demo to here: http://worldwindserver.net/java/2.0.0/demos/ApplicationTemplate.jnlp