# Run ActiveX object without allowing it in browser options

Tags: java, security, internet-explorer, applet, activex

How I can run ActiveX object in Internet explorer without allowing it Internet-explorer options?

Our customer can't allow using ActiveX for security reasons. But we need to use third party program, which have an ActiveX interface.

Can I wrap ActiveX object inside applet (or any other ideas?), so Internet Explorer don't know anything about ActiveX object being running inside applet (so IE don't show any security warnings)?

Comment: If ActiveX is disabled for security reasons, there are security reasons why it's disabled. Are you looking to exploit a security hole in the browser that would nevertheless do what's disallowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..ActiveX object being running inside applet (so IE don't show any security warnings)?

Only a trusted applet could use ActiveX objects.  The [prompts for trusting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12986334/418556) a Java applet are security warnings.

[image]

So, no.  A sand-boxed (unprompted) Java applet cannot call an ActiveX control at all.

But even a trusted applet is still subject to security from the browser or OS. E.G. if ActiveX is *disabled*, even a trusted applet could not enabled it.  Or if it could, that would be a security bug.  Let us know, and we'll get it fixed ASAP.

Comment: Hmm.Thanks. So it even impossible to use applet as container, as virtual machine for running `.exe` files? 
May be I can achieve my goal without using ActiveX at all? Using some applet specific functions to use `.exe` file? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: *"Using some applet specific functions to use .exe file? Any ideas?"*  A trusted applet can use an EXE.

Comment: ok, thanks again. Can you point me to some tutorial where explained how to use ActiveX inside applet? I understand, it very cheeky asked, but I really don't found any tutorial related with it. Thanks

Comment: Your Google is as good as mine.  I've never used ActiveX controls, in an applet or anything else.