# Launching a Java program via double click

Tags: java, macos, deployment, installation, executable-jar

I have a Java program that I have been working on. I would like to show it to my girlfriend, who would have no clue as to how to work with Java, and make it easy for her to do so.  I understand the first step is to compile it to .class 's from the command line, but after that I am clueless.

I would be interested in finding out how to do this *both* for Windows and Mac OS (I am on a Mac, along with my girlfriend, but my school uses Windows computers).

I have been on Oracle and seen their demos, they download as .jnlp, is that a step in the right direction?

And specifically, I am looking for a "file" of some sort that is simply downloaded and launched, no terminal involved (maybe a file with a command line within?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Launching a Java program via double click
>   ..seen .. demos, they download as .jnlp, is that a step in the right direction?

The title and that quote typically represent two different ways to launch Java desktop apps.

1. *"download as .jnlp"*  That is the 'deluxe' version, known as [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It is a little trickier for the developer (you) but very easy for the user (your friend).
2. *"Launching a Java program via double click"* is more commonly associated with an executable Jar. (Although JWS also supports the 'double click' - but with menus and shortcuts.)

Either strategy will work on OS X, Windows or *nix, but the first has JRE versioning (making sure the end user has a JRE, and it is recent enough to run the code) assisted by scripts, and many other 'bells and whistles'.

### Java Web Start

- JWS apps. typically deployed from a web page or server accessible to the user machine, so your friend 'surfs on over' to the link you sent her to 'Download here'.

  - The moment she arrives at your web page, the `deployJava.js` will check her PC has a suitable minimum version of Java to run the app. If not, she will be guided through a process to get it.
  - When the JRE is confirmed (which happens invisibly for those with a later JRE) the script writes a link in the web page that by default is a button. 
    [image]
- The user clicks the button and the JWS client (part of Java) will read the JNLP and begin to install the app.
- If the app., requires permissions extended beyond the default sand-box, the user will be prompted as to whether to allow the code to run. See [Appearance of Java Security dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986333/appearance-of-java-security-dialog) for more examples like:
  [image]
  If the user chooses <kbd>Run</kbd> ..
- The app. will be loaded and appear on-screen (possibly along with desktop shortcuts and start menu being added).
- To launch it the second and subsequent times, the user **double clicks** the desktop shortcut or **activates** the menu item.  This is how Starzoom (which has an icon defined in the JNLP) appears in Windows 7. 
  [image]

### Executable Jar

Another lesser alternative is an [executable-jar](/questions/tagged/executable-jar).

It uses a `manifest.mf` in the Jar that specifies the main class.

While being a lesser experience for the end user, it is also simpler for the developer - a trade off that might come in handy for limited distribution.

- Requires a suitable version JRE installed.
- The user obtains the Jar from whatever source (USB, Bluetooth, web site etc.) and saves it anywhere on their machine that is convenient.
- To launch it, the user **double clicks** the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bat script (Windows, I don't use OSX, but i think it's shell script for that) with the Java command you use to execute your Java program.

Or you could put you java class into a  [JAR file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try NetBeans, make a project in there, and build your codes with it. It automatically produce jar file that can be execute via double click almost in any platform.