# Java Swing - Change executable jar icon

Tags: java, swing, deployment, icons, executable-jar

[image]
Is there anyway I can change the icon in the executable jar file as screen shot attached. Any advice or reference link is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can change the icon in the executable jar..

You are thinking about this the wrong way around.  The user should never see the Jar/Exe.  Instead, they should be provided with a desktop (or wherever they expect to see apps. listed) shortcut or menu item with an icon.

For those, install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix, and **supports setting an image for the desktop short cut and menu item.**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14077978/418556) for more details..

[image]