# Java: Running this application may be a security risk

Tags: java, security

I made a java game and I want to run it locally with java web start on my computer. Every time I run the application from NetBeans I get this message, I would like to disable it. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157397/avoid-security-alert-do-you-want-to-run-this-application-for-a-jws-app) and [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html)