# Java applet on website does not scan other websites

Tags: java, url, web, applet

Hello I have just finished my very first applet in Java : 
http://st.fri.uniza.sk/~mudrak3/index2

What it does is basicaly it goes through websites source code and finds any links and appends them into textArea.

If I put that website link into textField (http://st.fri.uniza.sk/~mudrak3/index2) and hit button it all works. Button event :

```
private void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    textArea1.setText("\f");
    try {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> vystup = new ArrayList<String>();
        URL adresa;
        adresa = new URL(textField1.getText());
        BufferedReader kod = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(adresa.openStream()));
        String riadok;
        while ((riadok = kod.readLine()) != null) {
            array.add(riadok);
            String[] pom = riadok.split(" ");
            String xxx;
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://[^ \"]+");
            for (int i = 0; i < pom.length; i++) {
                xxx = pom[i];
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xxx);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    textArea1.append(matcher.group(0) + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        textArea1.append("---------Koniec---------");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Zle zadana URL !");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOException !");
    }

}
```

Any other website doesn't work. This app works in NetBeans as I run the applet, but not on the website. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reach across domains, an applet needs to be:

1. [Digitally signed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) by you.
2. Accepted by the user when [prompted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986333/appearance-of-java-security-dialog).

Comment: Thank you ! I did not know I have to sign such an applet. :)